# tornado websocket handler uncaught exception

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to catch uncaught exceptions in my WebSocketHandler. But Tornado's [WebSocketHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/websocket.html#WebSocketHandler) does not have the same exception handling interface as the HTTP RequestHandler.

In the above source, it looks like exceptions are caught and logged here:

```
def _run_callback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
    """Runs the given callback with exception handling.

    On error, aborts the websocket connection and returns False.
    """
    try:
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception:
        app_log.error("Uncaught exception in %s",
                      self.request.path, exc_info=True)
        self._abort()
```

Instead of hacking the handler and subclassing `WebSocketProtocol` which implements the above method, is there a better way to catch exceptions in the `WebSocketHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing and overriding `WebSocketProtocol._run_callback` is currently the best way to do this from a base class. But since it's cumbersome to subclass and override this method, it's probably better to handle this at the application level until [proper support can be added to the framework](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1981). Either wrap all your callbacks in a big try/except block or if you have enough of them that this gets irritating, you can make your own exception-catching decorator.